# In JQuery, how to parse comma delimited string into table cell elements?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 strings in PHP which are passed to JQuery as aData[4], aData[5] and aData[6]

such that:

```
        function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
    {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
        var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
        sOut += '<thead><tr><td>UPC</td><td>Item Description</td><td>Total</td></tr></thead>';
        sOut += '<tbody><tr><td>'+aData[4]+'</td><td>'+aData[5]+'</td><td>'+aData[6]+'</td></tr></tbody>';
        sOut += '</table>';

        return sOut;
    }
```

displays:

```
    UPC                         Description         Total
    0004712503209,0004712503201 MARIONBRY,APPLE PIE 37.65,33.29
```

I want to have one row per UPC/Description/Total, so the result is:

```
UPC             Description      Total
0004712503209   MARIONBRY        37.65
0004712503201   APPLE PIE        33.29
```

How do I parse these strings in JQuery?

Comment: split them with comma and loop through...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really jQuery that you need... just plain old JavaScript.

```
function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
{
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var length = aData[4].split(",").length;
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<thead><tr><td>UPC</td><td>Item Description</td><td>Total</td></tr></thead>';
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        sOut += '<tbody><tr><td>'+aData[4].split(",")[i]+'</td><td>'+aData[5].split(",")[i]+'</td><td>'+aData[6].split(",")[i]+'</td></tr></tbody>';
    }
    sOut += '</table>';

    return sOut;
}
```

Note, this isn't terribly efficient, because you're calling split three times for each loop iteration. This is just the quickest solution, without creating a whole lot of other variables, or otherwise complicating things further. (Btw, it's also assuming that the array length aData[4].split(",") will be exactly the same as `aData[5].split(",")` and `aData[6].split(",")`. But, again, this is the straightforward solution, with you being able to add whatever other worthy enhancements you deem necessary for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not doing it on the PHP side? You can do it in jQuery like below, but it won't work if the client has JavaScript disabled.

**jQuery:**

```
var newRow = '<tr>';
$('tbody tr').children().each(function() {
    var arr = $(this).html().split(',');
    $(this).html(arr[0]);
    newRow += '<td>' + arr[1] + </td>;
});
newRow += '</tr>';
$('tbody').append(newRow);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuGmW/)

PS: This only works if you have two values. You'll need to loop through the values and add new a new row for each one if you have more than 2.